# Wordpress monthly archive links result in 404

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, rewrite-rules

When I use the archive widget in a sidebar, it creates the normal monthly post archive listing like the following:

- February 2014
- January 2014
- October 2013

and so on.  Whenever I click on these links, I get a 404 page.

The urls generated by the archive widget for monthly listings are in this format:

> www.mysite.com/pedestrian/2014/02/

However, manually entering the following url style works:

> www.mysite.com/pedestrian/?post_type=news&year=2014&monthnum=02

This shows exactly what I would expect to see (all the posts from February 2014).

I believe that the following code will fix my issue, but I am at a loss as to where to put it.

```
// Add day archive (and pagination)
add_rewrite_rule("pedestrian/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]','top');
add_rewrite_rule("pedestrian/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/?",'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]','top');

// Add month archive (and pagination)
add_rewrite_rule("pedestrian/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]','top');
add_rewrite_rule("pedestrian/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?",'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]','top');

// Add year archive (and pagination)
add_rewrite_rule("pedestrian/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?",'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
add_rewrite_rule("pedestrian/([0-9]{4})/?",'index.php?post_type=news&year=$matches[1]','top');
```

So, am i on the right track and if so where do i put this code?  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is "pedestrian" in your URLs? Why do you think that code would address the issue?

Comment: I don't know if the code will work.. but if you need to put it somewhere put it in functions.php

Comment: pedestrian is just one of the pages on the site.  i just included it because i was copy and pasting from my site

Comment: How did you go with this @user47912? Did you end up finding a solution? Did @Wrought_steel's solution posted below work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add your news custom post type to the query for archive pages (I had the same problem).

[Codex: custom post types to query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types_in_the_Main_Query)

Add this code to your functions

```
    // Show posts of 'post', and 'news' post types on archive page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'news' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

Just check that your admin post listings are not affected.