# wordpress custom post type shows other cpt posts in admin menu

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I have a wordpress website with 4 custom post type and Suddenly 3 of them show the other one posts in admin menu.
what is the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i don't know why but the problem solved after i deleted the following question code from my function.php file

```
    // Show posts of 'post', and 'news' post types on archive page
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

    function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
        if ( is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() )
            $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'news' ) );
        return $query;
    }
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136115/94280

Comment: What code? May you please update your answer?

Comment: is_archive should only be true on the front end of the site on post archive pages, so that code shouldn't affect the admin anyway.

Comment: tnx @AndyMacaulay-Brook